# Is it break my for loop in c++?

Tags: c++, for-loop, break

```
for(size_t i=0;i<vec.size();i++){
    if(n>vec[i]){
        a=i;
        break;
    }
}
```

in this example, am I breaking the if statement or the for loop?

Comment: Just try it: ideone.com

Comment: You should be using `std::find_if` anyway.

Comment: You can't break if statement...

Comment: Feel free to use `goto` instead if you find that more readable.

Comment: Er, no. `break` is short for `goto` to an implicit label at the end of the current iteration statement, and there is nothing wrong with actually naming that label, especially when things get more complicated (nested loops for instance).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *break* statement is used to break out of a *switch* or *iteration statement* i.e. a while, do or for loop. The [C++ draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `6.6.1` *The break statement* says:

> The break statement shall occur only in an iteration-statement or a switch statement and causes termination of the smallest enclosing iteration-statement or switch statement; control passes to the statement following the terminated statement, if any.

Since the *if* is not an *iteration statement* or a *switch* then the *break* will leave the *for* loop.

Answer (score 1):

A `break` statement ends only the `do`, `for`, `switch`, or `while` statement that immediately encloses it.  It doesn't break out of an if statement, so your code is breaking out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

It will break from the **for** loop.

> In loops, the break statement ends execution of the nearest enclosing
>   **do**, **for**, or **while** statement.

**Source:** [Microsoft docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37zc9d2w.aspx)